# python selenium, cant't click element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i'm having a problem with selenium. I load this page: [Investing 3M](https://www.investing.com/equities/3m-co-financial-summary), and i want to click got it in a pop-out window.

[image: investing got it window]

I already tryed with this code bellow, but it doesn't work:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.investing.com/equities/3m-co-financial-summary")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
x =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]")
print(len(x))
print(x)
```

Can anyone provide any solution to this?

Comment: How do you get the popup to show?

Comment: When page is fully loaded this popup shows automatically, this popup happens only on chrome driver and not in normal chrome.

Comment: it may accept escape key to close and that'll be pretty easy to do... just switch the driver to the active element and send Keys.ESCAPE.  (WebElement element = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
  element.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE); in Java... don't know python...)

Comment: In java, once modal popup appeared, I usually do `driver.switchTo().activeElement();` then `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Got it')]").click();`

Answer (score 0):

The element is present inside an **iframe**.You need to switch to frame first.

To handle dynamic element you need to

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() and following `xpath`

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `xpath`

**code**:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.investing.com/equities/3m-co-financial-summary")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager']")))
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Got it']"))).click()
```

Browser snapshot after clicking

[image]